# How to return a jQuery attr variable from an array to it's original object?

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, attributes, href

I wanted to find out the best method via jQuery to return an inital href attribute back to its original element.

I am working on a menu made of list items which contain anchor tags within.
Since the menu item's anchor's hrefs need to equal javascript:void(0) if they have the class of .dropdown-toggle, when in mobile/tablet view for button/accordion purposes, I need to swap out the anchor's hrefs when under 785px width browser window.

I have successfully done so, however the challenge is once the window is restored to a desktop view, the anchor's hrefs need to return to their original value, an actual link, rather than an accordion button.

I am attempting to restore the original URL by first creating a global array of original URL's which has been a success. Looping through them and returning them to their own current element, which is where I am struggling. Here is what I have below.

Thanks in advance!

```
var links = $('a.dropdown-toggle').map(function() { return this.href }).get()
function mobileNavStyles() {
   var $containerWidth = $(window).width();
   if ($containerWidth <= 785) {
      $('.dropdown-toggle').attr("href", "javascript:void(0)"); 
   }
   if($containerWidth > 785) {
        $.each( links, function( intValue, currentElement ) {
            return $(this).attr('href', currentElement);
        });
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't do this:

```
$('.dropdown-toggle').attr("href", "javascript:void(0)");
```

Keep your `href`, but disable the link by returning false from an event handler:

```
function mobileNavStyles() {
   var $containerWidth = $(window).width();
   $('.dropdown-toggle').unbind('click');
   if ($containerWidth <= 785)
      $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function(){ return false; }); 
}
```

**Edit**: If you have other `click` handlers on `.dropdown-toggle` you can use `bind` and name your handler like so:

```
function mobileNavStyles() {
   var $containerWidth = $(window).width();
   $('.dropdown-toggle').unbind('click.canceller');
   if ($containerWidth <= 785)
      $('.dropdown-toggle').bind('click.canceller', function(){ return false; }); 
}
```

Comment: Excellent lightweight solution! Thank you!

Comment: I do have one question for you @Paulpro , If the .click event handler is returned false, how could you add a .click event for it to do something else? Like toggle a class on a child li?

Comment: @OwenMack You can use `bind` instead of `click` and then give you're handler a name. I have updated my answer.